# Definition of a perfect point set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was reading an [older paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1935-41-04/S0002-9904-1935-06049-5/S0002-9904-1935-06049-5.pdf) and at one point they mention something called a "perfect point set" - it's in the lemma on the second page. I ran into trouble trying to find an actual definition. Is it simply a "perfect set", or is there more to it?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is simply a perfect set in the usual Cantor sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s just a perfect set, i.e., a closed set with no isolated points. The lemma is just (a case of) the Baire category theorem.